# Xamarin.Android, AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifestMerger, xmlns:tools schema, replace always manually

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-manifest

When compile my Xamarin Forms Android application, visual studio, show me an error's list of AndroidManifest.xml conflict, for example:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error AMM0000:  is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-41 value=(@string/app_name). (AMM0000)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error AMM0000:  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:3-79:17 to override. (AMM0000)
```

So i open AndroidManifest.xml from debug folder, replace with tools:replace into application tag, add tools schema into manifest tag, save it, recompile my application and it run without error.

**But WHENEVER i compile my Xamarin Forms Android application, must follow previous steps MANUALLY**.

I also add `<AndroidManifestMerger>manifestmerger.jar</AndroidManifestMerger>`, into my Android .csproj

This issue is showed into DEBUG and RELEASE mode!!

Environment

- Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.6.4
- Xamarin Forms = 4.7.0.968
- Xamarin.Android = Versione: 10.3.1.4

Comment: What does `must follow previous steps MANUALLY` mean? When you debug the code, you need to do it everything before debugging?

Comment: Ok, i explain step by step: 
1)Start Debug, and show compiler's error: AndroidManifest conflict (error above).
2)Next i open AndroidManifest.xml from Android project obj/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and add to manifest tag tools:replace="android:label" and to application tag xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
3)Save AndroidManifest from obj/debug and restart Debug, and app start without errors.

Now you stop debug and edit your code and restart debug Android project repeat step from the first!

Comment: Check also https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/182999/xamarin-android-androidmanifest-xml-androidmanifestmerger-xmlns-tools-schema-replace-always-manu#latest

Comment: I got it. You mean every time debug the code need to add the `tools:replace` into AndroidManifest.xml. Does this occur on every project include a new project which you do nothing?

Comment: Yes, every time debug i need to add the mentioned tags, manually, into AndroidManifest.xml file!

New Project Work without add tags!

Comment: It is so strange, the AndroidManifest.xml file does not save the changes. I cannot reproduce. Could you check the Xamarin.Forms version? Does it to be the same with Droid project?

Answer (score 13):

This is an [issue with Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11233) 4.6.0.967 and above. To me, it was provoked by using the Honeywell.BarcodeReader NuGet package.

Some AndroidX packages were overwriting the default Xamarin (soon to be legacy) manifest merger with the manifestmerger.jar.

A workaround is to downgrade to Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.847, or to modify your AndroidManifest.xml to have an application element like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" tools:replace="android:label" ...
```

or if there are more conflicts:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" tools:node="replace"...
```

You will also need to add the following namespace to the manifest as an attribute:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution.

`Build > Clean Solution`

`Build > Rebuild Solution`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Yves answer....

It appears that the manifestmerger is not able to merge the AndroidManifest.xml from multiple projects in the Android solution.

When modifying your AndroidManifest.xml you may need to add multiple entries to the "tools:replace application tag such as label and theme.

```
<application 
   tools:replace="android:label, android:theme"
   android:label="XamarinDemo.Android" 
   android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
</application>
```