# Is there a way to fix error: AMM0000 when I try to upgrade Framework to Android 10.0 Q on Visual Studio

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk

I'm trying to upgrade the app to work on android 10 with visual studio /mac/.

From SDK Manager -> I download Android SDK Platform29.
From Properties on the project options I changed framework from 9.0 Pie to 10Q

So when I try to build the app I receive this errors:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3):
Error AMM0000: /Users/../obj/Debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 
Error: (AMM0000) (appName)
```

Тhe other consecutive errors are:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): 
Error AMM0000:  Attribute application@appComponentFactory 
value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) 
from AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 (AMM0000) (WeatherApp.Android)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): 
Error AMM0000:  is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory). (AMM0000) (AppName)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): 
    Error AMM0000:  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' 
    to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:3-25:17 to override. 
    (AMM0000) (WeatherApp.Android)
```

Every error send me in some xamarin.android.common.targets file on this part of code:

```
 <ManifestMerger
  ToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
  JavaOptions="$(JavaOptions)"
  ManifestMergerJarPath="$(AndroidManifestMergerJarPath)"
  AndroidManifest="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AndroidManifest.xml"
  OutputManifestFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
  LibraryManifestFiles="@(ExtractedManifestDocuments)"
  ManifestPlaceholders="$(AndroidManifestPlaceholders)"/>
```

Is there a way fix the errors .. ?

SDK Platform29 /Android 10.0 - Q

[image: SDK Platform29 /Android 10.0 - Q]

The Errors after try to build app.

[image: The Errors after try to build app.]

I try to clean the build and I have this error:

```
 Binary XML file line #1 in com.companyname.WeatherApp:layout/toolbar:
 Binary XML file line #1 in com.companyname.WeatherApp:layout/toolbar:
 Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

[image: Handle Specified cast is not valid]

So the error is on this line of code:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace WeatherApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "WeatherApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11233 and there is another discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62487423/xamarin-android-androidmanifest-xml-androidmanifestmerger-xmlnstools-schema) may be helpful.

Comment: Clean Build work fine ;) but I have the last error from Handle - Specified cast is not valid ?

Comment: Hi, where is the error occurs? You could update in question, and it always happens the type of object can not be used directly. You need to convert it then use can use it.

Comment: the specified error is on this line: base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Okey, this line can not know where problem is. If you can find detailed line code, that will be possible to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter this problem, I create a new project with the same name and transfer the AndroidManifest.xml file to the new project.

Comment: It worked. However what you mean is : "I create a new project in a different directory with the same project name and copy the AndroidManifest file from the NEW project and overwrite it on the old one in the OLD project.